# C - Build/Compile/Deploy success but on other machine its failing

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, eid

I have C code for reading ID card reader, it compiled/build/executes fine in my development PC (Windows 10), where i have my Visual studio 2015.

But when i am running the `eid.exe` to a brand new (Windows 10) machine for unit testing, there its keep showing following error (also installed https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145 ):

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are deploying a debug build of your application (as evidenced by failing to find the debug versions of the runtime files `VCRUNTIME140D.dll` and `ucrtbased.dll`). The solution is simple: Don't deploy debug builds.<sup>*</sup>

If you need to deploy a debug release for testing, you need to acquire a Visual Studio license for your test machine. Although it is highly dubious to test code that will not be published. You should really test the release configuration instead.

---

<sup>*</sup> *The debug versions of the CRT are part of Visual Studio and cannot be redistributed.*

**EDIT:**

Step 1:

[image]

Step 2:

[image]

Step 3: Fix the target's

[image]

Step 4: fix the Includes

[image]

Step 5: optionally additional includes

[image]

WORKS: 
[image]